# rasa init failed - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: anaconda, rasa

rasa init is failing with below error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command
```

Tried with both miniconda as well as full anaconda